# Why isn't my char* shrinking after popping a char

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

For context, I'm rewriting the `string` class in C++ to use on microcontrollers, specifically Arduino, so that it doesn't use the standard library functions not supported by Arduino.

I've looked at several answers here that show how to pop a char off a `char*`. However, within my function it doesn't seem to correctly edit the `char*`.

My string class

```
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc

namespace micro_std {

    class string {

        private:
            const int MAX_SIZE = 4096; // Maximum size on 16bit controllers.
            
            char* data = nullptr;
            int _length = 0;

        public:
            string(char* data) {
                this->data = data;
                for (int i = 0; data[i] != '\0'; i++)
                    _length++;
            }

            int size(void)     const { return _length;              }
            int length(void)   const { return _length;              }
            int max_size(void) const { return MAX_SIZE;             }
            bool empty(void)   const { return _length == 0;         }
            char at(int index) const { return data[index];          }
            char back(void)    const { return data[_length - 1];    }
            char front(void)   const { return data[0];              }
            char* str(void)    const { return data;                 }
            void clear(void)         { _length = 0; data = nullptr; }

            // removed for brevity //

            char pop_back(void) {
                _length--;
                char character = data[_length];
                data[_length] = '\0';
                return character;
            }

            // removed for brevity //
            
    };

}
```

And how I'm testing my code, specifically the `pop_back` function.

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include "micro_std/string.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    micro_std::string x = "abcdef";

    // Testing pop_back function

    printf("%d   %s\n", x.length(), x.str());
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        char res = x.pop_back();
        printf("%d %c %s\n", x.length(), res, x.str());
    }
    //printf("%s\n", x.str());

    return 0;

}
```

And, if needed, my compiler arguments

```
g++ -w -std=c++2a -O3 program.cpp -o program
```

Running this program gives me the following output:

```
6   abcdef
5 f abcdef
4 e abcdef
3 d abcdef
2 c abcdef
1 b abcdef
```

Instead of the output I want:

```
6   abcdef
5 f abcde
4 e abcd
3 d abc
2 c ab
1 b a
```

Where the output is formatted like "(length) (char popped) (result string)". Why isn't the data member `data` being altered when calling the `pop_back` function?

Comment: Firstly, there are somewhat strict rules about what you can and cannot add to namespace std and I'm pretty sure adding string is against it (at the very least its *very* confusing). Secondly, your string constructor is taking a char* but youre passing in a const char* (the string literal "abcdef") which loses the const qualifier and I'm not even sure how this compiles at all. And if it does I'm pretty sure that is UB. You should be making a copy of that input literal and operate on the copy (that's what the real std::string does)

Comment: The code goes off the rails by having `std::string` mean something else.  And as mentioned, the program should have never been created, since it is an error to pass a string-literal as a `char *`.

Comment: I changed `std` to `micro_std` to avoid name conflicts, and I'm still not getting the desired output.

Comment: Again, that program you're running is ill-formed -- it shouldn't even exist.  Fix that issue, and *maybe* the output will be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why isn't the data member data being altered when calling the pop_back function?

Even if the code compiles (which it shouldn't, since you are trying to construct `x` with a *string literal*, which is a `const char[]` array that cannot be assigned to a non-const `char*`), `x` would be pointing its `data` member at a string literal, thus `data[_length] = '\0';` inside of `pop_back()` would invoke **Undefined Behavior** trying to alter read-only memory.

To make your code work, you MUST make a *copy* of the input data, eg:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc

namespace micro_std {

    class string {

        private:
            const int MAX_SIZE = 4096; // Maximum size on 16bit controllers.
            
            char _data[MAX_SIZE];
            int _length = 0;

        public:
            string(const char* str) {
                for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
                    data[i] = str[i];
                    ++_length;
                }
                data[_length] = '\0';
            }

           ...
           void clear(void)         { _length = 0; }
           ... 
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's strange how, even after enabling all warning flags in g++, it doesn't give me a warning that I'm attempting to modify a constant value.

Comment: @Linny -- There is no way the compiler can detect what that `char *` is pointing to at the point where you are modifying the value.  Imagine if that function was located in a far-flung module somewhere -- how would the compiler know that `char *` is pointing to a modifiable buffer?

Comment: @Linny "*it doesn't give me a warning that I'm attempting to modify a constant value*" - because it can't. First, it doesn't know that you are pointing at read-only memory. Second, your pointer being declared as non-const promises to point only ever at modifyable memory. But you are breaking that promise.

Comment: Yep, I understand now. I can't edit read-only memory and the compiler doesn't know that I'm trying to. I just looked at your code, edited mine to fit accordingly, and it worked. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thus your answer saying  "Even if the code compiles (which it shouldn't..." ...

Comment: @Linny *"It's strange how, even after enabling all warning flags in g++,"* -- you seem to have misread the manual. Your command line does not enable all warnings. You used `-w`, and according to the man page for gcc: `-w  Inhibit all warning messages.` Your command turned **off** all warnings, not on. Try using `-Wall -Wextra` instead (capital 'W' on those).

Comment: I'd add also `-Wpedantic -Wconversion`